# Zend_Cache Clean Method

Tags: zend-framework, caching

I just tried to use Zend_Cache in my application, and it worked. The problem now is I am not sure where to put Zend_Cache clean() method in my code.
Here is my code:

```
// application/Bootstrap.php
protected function _initCache()
{

    $dir = "./cache";

    $frontendOptions = array(
            'lifetime' => 10,
            'content_type_memorization' => true,
            'default_options'           => array(
                    'cache' => true,
                    'cache_with_get_variables' => true,
                    'cache_with_post_variables' => true,
                    'cache_with_session_variables' => true,
                    'cache_with_cookie_variables' => true,
            ),
            'regexps' => array(
                    // cache the whole IndexController
                    '^/.*' => array('cache' => true),
                    '^/index/' => array('cache' => true),
                    // place more controller links here to cache them
            )
    );

    $backendOptions = array(
            'cache_dir' =>$dir
    );

    // getting a Zend_Cache_Frontend_Page object
    $cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Page',
            'File',
            $frontendOptions,
            $backendOptions);
    $cache->start();
}
```

Where should I put the `$cache->clean(/* something */);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have configured our $frontend array to cache data for 10 seconds, so the data cached will automatically be remove after 10 second.

i would suggest that you can increase your time like

```
one hour : 3600 or 2 hours like 7200
```

However if later in your application you want to clean the entire cached data manually, simply write

$cache->clean();

This will clean the entire cached data. However if you want to remove specific data being cached, write

$cache->remove(‘mydata’);

for more use of cache see [link](http://zendguru.wordpress.com/2008/12/01/caching-data-using-zend_cache-with-example/)

*i am not associate with above link it is just for your knowledge*

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: @Andy Wijaya,i am sure my answer is sure help you and it would be glad for me if you will acept my answer